# Laravel auto-publish the package configs to the project

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

I have some config files in my package that wanted to be copied over to the project or app config directory. I know how to publish it manually by running the command `php artisan vendor:publish`. Anyone here knows how to publish them automatically? Like I don't have to remember that I have some config files in my packages when I install the app in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in composer.json of the project. Just need to add a command in the scripts section, under `post-autoload-dump`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi",
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag={tagNameHere}--force"
     ]
   },
```

I defined the tag at my package ServiceProvider.php:

```
  public function boot()
  {
    $this->publishes([
        //file source => file destination below
        __DIR__.'/config/someconfig.php' => config_path('someconfig.php'),
       //you can also add more configs here
      ],
      ['tagNameHere'] //this is the tag so you can run the command as php artisan vendor:publish --force --tag=tagNameHere, for more info run php artisan vendor:publish --help
    );
  }
```

Every time I run `composer update` or `composer dump-autoload`, the configs of my dependency is automatically copied over so I don't have to remember that I have something to publish.

Comment: Hi @kriscondev, your solution is nice but I'm wondering if using --force will rewrite the config file everytime that for some reason composer recreates the autoload, did you experience this issue?